# How do i assign same list object to two different variable names in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, memory-management, namespaces

I have been trying to solve this silly bubble sorting program i received in my high school, I attempted to make a autosorting class(See the code) just for the fun of it, But then, Something is troubling me

```
class AutoSortedArray:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.lenarr = len(array)
        self.unsorted = array
        OGL = list(array)
        self.sorted = self.bsort(OGL)


    def bsort(self, array):
        for i in range(self.lenarr):
            for j in range(0, self.lenarr-i-1):
                if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                    array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]

        return tuple(array)


if __name__=="__main__":

    ASA=AutoSortedArray((5,8,2,1,3,6,4,7))

    print(ASA.unsorted)
    print(ASA.sorted)
```

Now the problem is, The argument passed to my class the 'array' seems to be pointing to the same memory address whenever i try to assign it to different variables, But i need to do that because i need the **'unsorted' name untouched**, But python assigning the same memory address to all names referencing array creates problems for me, the name unsorted always get modified and altered in the end and both ASA.unsorted and ASA.sorted give out the same result where my array is pre-sorted

Now this problem wont be happening if it was happening in the main block, As the OGL name getting modified would've assigned it a separate new memory address, But that does not seem to be happening here probably due to some class thing.

So here are my questions:

1. Can i assign two different mutable objects to the same value in python(Without using some silly bypass like OGL = array[::1]), If possible, how?
2. Why is this happening in my current code even though OGL gets modified by bsort's action, Shouldnt it be assigned a new memory address when it is modified?
3. Does the same happen in other OOP languages like C++/Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the unsorted array not be referenced further from sorted array then you must perfom deep copy for that.

```
class AutoSortedArray:
    def __init__(self, array):
        self.lenarr = len(array)
        self.unsorted = tuple(list(array).copy())
        OGL = list(array)
        self.sorted = self.bsort(OGL)

    def bsort(self, array):
        for i in range(self.lenarr):
            for j in range(0, self.lenarr-i-1):
                if array[j] > array[j+1]:
                    array[j], array[j+1] = array[j+1], array[j]

        return tuple(array)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    ASA = AutoSortedArray((5, 8, 2, 1, 3, 6, 4, 7))

    print(ASA.unsorted)
    print(ASA.sorted)
```

Comment: Thank you!
That was the kind of fix i was looking for! G' Day!

Comment: If it has solved your query, then you may mark the answer as accepted.